# JProfiler evt versus inv

Tags: jprofiler

In jprofiler's CPU Views tab, the call graph typically displays the number of invocations of each method (ex, 214 inv.).  However, on some of my methods, it shows "evt." instead (ex, 460 evt.).  What does evt stand for, and how does it differ from number of invocations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the thread status selection. For "All states" and "Runnable" JProfiler shows **invocations**, hence "inv.". For "Waiting", "Blocked" and "Net IO", it shows the cumulated number of **events** ("evt.") that are associated with the selected thread status. This is not necessarily the same as the number of times the methods in the call tree have been invoked.

Comment: Thanks!  For future reference, I found this site to help explain events:  http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/probes/probesOverview.html